# How do I recursively nest two queries from the same table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

So I have a table named "data" as follows:

```
ID|Name
--|----
01|Bob
01|John
01|Hal
02|Bob
02|Mike
03|Hal
03|Mike
03|John
03|Dave
04|Hal
04|Bob
```

I can build a query like

```
SELECT ID FROM data WHERE Name='Bob';
```

and I get the result 01, 02, 04 as expected. Now what I'd like to do is within the same query, ask for all of the names associated with those IDs. Something like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM data WHERE ID=1 OR ID=2 OR ID=4;
```

Which gives me the result of Bob, John, Hal, Bob, Mike, Dave, Bob

Except what I really want is

```
SELECT Name FROM data WHERE ID=(SELECT ID FROM data WHERE Name='Bob';);
```

Which should give me the result of Bob, John, Hal, Bob, Mike, Hal, Bob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after the "IN" operator

```
select a.name from data a where a.ID in (select b.ID from data b where b.Name = 'Bob');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT Name FROM data WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM data WHERE Name = 'Bob');
```

`IN` is used as ID has to be compared against multiple results produced by the sub-query.